# Stretch texture over multiple faces

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I have a sphere with a slightly curved top and I applied a grass texture to the top, but what it is doing is applying the texture to every face, which is much too small.
[image]
I want it to be larger so that it looks better and the tileing is less noticeable.
In edit mode and close up it looks like:
[image: More close up photo in edit mode]

I will need to export the model as an obj so the texture would need to look the same when exported.

Comment: Did you uv unwrap it?

Comment: Instead of UV texture co-ordinates why not use object? Then scale with a transform node.